# ¿Cómo generar en C# un webservice que incluya el schema en el response?

Tags: c#, webservice, soap

Tengo este código en C# (probablemente tiene algunos lapsus)...

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.i.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class MyWS : WebService
{
    [WebMethod()]
    public Tipos getTipos()
    {
        var ret = new Tipos();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string query = "SELECT Id, Cod, Tipo FROM Tipos";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbContext"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var lst = new List<Tipos>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string cod = reader.GetString(1);
                string gls = reader.GetString(2);
                lst.Add(new Tipos { Id = id, Cod = cod, Tipo = gls });
            }
            ret = lst;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public class Tipos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Cod { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

... con lo cual obtengo lo siguiente:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    <soap:Body>
      <getTiposResponse xmlns="http://www.i.com/">
         <getTiposResult>
            <Tipos>
               <Id>1</Id>
               <Cod>CAL</Cod>
               <Tipo>Calle</Tipo>
            </Tipos>
            <Tipos>
               <Id>2</Id>
               <Cod>AV</Cod>
               <Tipo>Avenida</Tipo>
            </Tipos>
         </getTiposResult>
      </getTiposResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

...Pero yo necesito que se incluya en la cabecera del SOAP el schema, que corresponde a la clase de C#:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getTiposResponse xmlns="http://www.exsoli.cl/">
         <getTiposResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Table1">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Cod" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Tipo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
               <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <Id>1</Id>
                     <Cod>CAL</Cod>
                     <Tipo>Calle</Tipo>
                  </Table1>
                  <Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <Id>2</Id>
                     <Cod>AV</Cod>
                     <Tipo>Avenida</Tipo>
                  </Table1>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </getTipoCalleResult>
      </getTipoCalleResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Este requerimiento es para compatibilidad con VisualFoxPro. El segundo SOAP lo obtuve usando un DataSet genérico en vez de una clase, pero lamentablemente requiero la clase, no me sirve retornar el DataSet ¿Qué me falta?

Comment: Intenta poner el atributo `[Serializable()]` a la clase,a ver si asi te lo genera aunque no estoy seguro...

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias, pero `[Serializable()]` no cambia nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien el problema pero para poder hacer eso, deberías usar un Typed DataSet o simplemente definir una clase y una lista de elementos y convertir tu dataset en la lista antes de devolverlo. Se añade una transformación... pero funciona.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Recomiendo que agregue un ejemplo claro de lo que se pretende con la respuesta, ya que los enlaces externos pueden fallar en ocasiones

Comment: El enlace es meramente accesorio. Se añade por si alguien pasa por aquí y no sabe lo que es un Typed Dataset. Además es un enlace a la documentación de Microsoft no es un enlace a un post en un grupo perdido.

Comment: La cuestion no es el enlace a donde apunta, lo que me refiero es que es mas conveniente si se agrega un ejemplo de lo que refieres, siempre y cuando sea posible

Comment: Prefiero hacer una respuesta concisa y directa. Si no se sabe que es un Typed Dataset o como hacerlo, pongo un enlace... si no funciona ese enlace, queda Google o abrir otra pregunta. Hay que ser concisos, nadie quiere leer 6 páginas de ejemplos que no aportan nada. Además estas metadiscusiones no aportan nada. Si el autor de la pregunta indica que necesita más ayuda si que le pondría ejemplos pero parecer que no es necesario. Creo que es mejor dejar las metadiscusiones para otro sitio y lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un archivo xsd.exe que con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
 xsd EnvioCFE.xsd ACKCFE_DGI.xsd ACKCFE_Partes.xsd ACKRepDiario.xsd ACKSobre.xsd CAE.xsd CFEDGI.xsd CFEEmpresas.xsd CFEs_Anulados_x_RechazoDGI.xsd DGITypes.xsd EnvioCFE_entreEmpresas.xsd ReporteDiarioCFE.xsd  /t:lib /l:cs /c /n:amersoft  xmldsig-core-schema.xsd  xenc-schema.xsd >> reporte.txt
```

amersoft    : es para el nombre del namespace

reporte.txt : es para generar un archivo con todo lo que hace

esto va a generar un archivo con un nombre muy largo formado por los nombres de los archivos *.xsd (que obtuviste de la pagina de dgi: XSDs_FE_1_36_.zip) y es un archivo .cs

Comment: Mariano - por que no puedo indicarle a Rodrigo que se comunique conmigo ?